# How to block No-user-agent browsers and browser with Tachiyomi user agent on my website using .htacess

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

tachiyomi keeps adding and removing user agents to get access to my website, so I want to add multiple user agents at the same time to get the things done

I know that I can use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Tachiyomi [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

but how to include both in the same?

Comment: And when it adds a user agent which looks like a legitimate browser, what will you do then? Why do you object to whatever this service is accessing your site?

Comment: let's talk to find out way to block it , i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OR` flag on the `RewriteCond` directive. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Tachiyomi [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

So the above rule is successful when the `User-Agent` string is either empty or a single hyphen *OR* contains "Tachiyomi" (case-insensitive).

Without the `OR` flag, the *conditions* are implicitly AND'd.

Multiple flags are separated by a comma (there must be no *spaces*). eg. `[NC,OR]`. The order of the flags do not matter.

NB: You must not use the `OR` flag on the very last *condition*, otherwise the rule will *always* be successful.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond